# having trouble with celery task chainging and errorhandling

Tags: python, parsing, celery

I have an application that loops through a list of files.  It parses the files and loads the parsed contents into a database.  Finally it moves the files to a `dump` directory.

I want to chain the tasks such that once a `SUCCESS` state is returned from the database loading the file can be moved.  However I still want to be able to catch exceptions and handle them at each step.

I have tried:

```
parse_file.apply_async(kwargs={'csvfile': current_file, ...},
                       link=move_file.s(current_file, dump_path),
                       link_error=error_handler.s())
```

but I am not sure this is correct since the `move_file` task is not getting called.

Comment: You are sure that parse_file is returning SUCCESS?

Comment: I want to chain the tasks such that once a SUCCESS state is returned from the database loading the file can be moved.

Comment: Yes but are you sure that the `parse_file` task is completing successfully? Can you add some output from the celery worker and master processes?

Comment: I am pulling the state and it returns with SUCCESS and PENDING.  I want to kick off another task to move the recently loaded file to another location.